# The requested URL was not found on this server apache2/ubuntu

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, apache2

Есть форма и контроллер.В них все верно. Не могу настроить apache2, что бы видел файлы. Пробовал через apache2.conf=>

```
<Directory /var/www/ittrainee/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

потом пробовал через настройку самого сайта

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ittrainee
ServerAlias www.ittrainee
ServerAdmin webmaster@ittrainee
DocumentRoot /var/www/ittrainee/www/
<Directory /var/www/ittrainee/www/>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Уже не знаю что делать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
<Directory /var/www/ittrainee>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Т.е. убрал 1 слеш.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Лог  апача покажите

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Nov/2018:23:55:59 +0200] "POST /controllers/FormController.php HTTP/1.1" 404 519 "http://ittrainee/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/70.0.3538.77 Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/ittrainee/www  , тоже слеш лишний. в /etc/hosts записать строку 127.0.0.1 ittrainee , service apache2 restart

Comment: это все прописанно,все равно не помогает.